# Maven Configuration : org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo

Tags: maven

I am using Eclipse Neon and Eclipse oxygen. I created a maven project and I get the below error in the pom.xml file.:

Maven Configuration Problem: org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo

For some reason it only happen on 1 laptop.

On another laptop I did the same thing but don't get the error.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it.

Comment: Could you run maven with `-e` option and provide error stacktrace in your question?

Comment: Please show the full error log output here...and of course your pom file and how you called Maven?

Answer (score 1):

Go to pom.xml file ->Overview->Artifact->Packaging->select JAR OK.

But in your project it is war.

Comment: I am also facing same issue